# Android: Align one element below and in the middle of another

Tags: android, alignment

I have an `ImageView` and `TextView`. I want to place the `TextView` below the image view but with the middle of the `TextView` aligned with the middle of the `ImageView` (along the horizontal axis). If the text in the `TextView` changes to something much larger or smaller, the middle of the text always needs to remain aligned with the middle of the `ImageView`. Is this possible in `xml`?

Comment: I think this is called the middle puzzle!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are simply looking to contain both elements in a vertical `LinearLayout` which has `android:gravity` set to `center_horizontal`.

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    ... >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

Because the `TextView`'s width is `wrap_content`, setting its gravity shouldn't be necessary. I would do it just for safety (and additionally, I may set the width to `match_parent` as well).

Comment: That's embarrassing because I already do that in another place in code. Thanks anyway.

Comment: So, it works for your purpose? If it's the solution, consider marking it as correct so others can find it as well.

Comment: You can't mark it right away. You have to wait several minutes. Patients. I almost always mark them.

Answer (score 0):

set `TextView`  `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and set `android:gravity="center"` in `TextView`.

I think it help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of RealtiveLayout as follows..

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    ... >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... />

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want your textview to be of single line only then add following properties to TextView

android:ellipsezed="end"
android:singleLine="true"

Use a given layout and add it to any of your existing layout you get result what your looking for ..

Hope this explanation works for you..